# Dynamic Datasources at Runtime AFTER configuration Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite, jpa, spring-mvc

If you look at the link below you can see very clearly how to define your datasources and your entity manager factories in code that is annotated to run during config.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e993

What I want to know is if there is a way of doing this after initialization? I want to dynamically create datasources to sqlite files that users are going to be uploading to extract information and put it into a mysql db on the server. I usa hibernate and jpa  for persistence and orm, and spring repositories for all of my db access. I know that I could use jdbc and access the info out of sqlite using queries but I already have lots of code written to be able to copy this data around so it would be really convenient to not have to write all of those queries and rewrite that code.

I could use a pool of files that I iterate in between clearing them out so that I can jsut replace those sqlite files with the uploaded ones and access those predefined ones but that is not very desirable. I would prefer to be able to upload a file, declare it as a new sqlite datasource and then provide that to my abstract routing datasource so that I can switch inbetween my datasources.

Right now I am defining my datasources in xml and I just switch between them using my abstract routing datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to inject the `EntityManagerFactory` instance in a wrapper and let all the code that needs an `EntityManager` call this wrapper. The wrapper would also provide a `setDataSource` method that can take an SQLite file or a DataSource constructed with all paramters, sets the data source of the `EntityManagerFactory` instance through reflection. So, subsequent `EntityManager` instances from this `EntityManagerFactory` would be using the same persistence unit but against the new SQLite data source.